# How to get value passed in Input Tag to href Tag Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an `<input>` tag in my webpage whose value needs to be passed to the `href` tag in Thymeleaf.

```html
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" th:value="*{pass}" placeholder = "Password">
<a th:href="@{~/updatepassword?password={pass}'&token={toke}(pass=${pass},toke=${token})}">Val</a>
```

However, the passed value from the input field is coming as empty.

What can be done here to properly pass the value?

Comment: @g00glen00b I accept the point but I want to pass the value inputted by the user in the input tag to href and I have seen many StackOverflow users using this method but yet I am using it. It's unsuccessfully...

Comment: I got it @g00glen00b I am using `th:attr= "value=${token}"` that automatically takes my thymeleaf variable and passes it to the URL